# How does Kubernetes create the Leases resource for an ETCD cluster to view the leader information?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

How does Kubernetes create the Leases resource for an ETCD cluster to view the leader information?

```
$ kubectl get leases
NAME                      HOLDER                                                       AGE
kube-controller-manager   master01.k8s-host.com_68f9a489-4e8c-4dc6-a9c2-6136d4cf7798   22h
kube-scheduler            master01.k8s-host.com_b1a8a9a3-e2bb-4102-84a4-b046b8776bdb   21h
```

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.8", GitCommit:"5575935422cc1cf5169dfc8847cb587aa47bac5a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T13:00:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
$ etcd version
etcd Version: 3.4.16
Git SHA: d19fbe541
Go Version: go1.12.17
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer that may help you. However, maybe you want to rephrase the "How does Kubernetes create the Leases resource". Tbh not clear whether you wanna check verbose output of whats going on in the background or you wanna understand the main idea and steps.

What I found is pretty comprehensive etcd article [Getting Started with Kubernetes | etcd | LEASE part](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/getting-started-with-kubernetes-%7C-etcd_596292)

> Lease is commonly used to represent a distributed lease in distributed
> systems. Typically, the lease mechanism is required to detect whether
> a node is alive in a distributed system.

[image]

> As shown in the preceding figure, a 10-second lease is created. If you
> do not perform any operations after the lease is created, the lease
> automatically expires after 10 seconds. Bind key1 and key2 to the
> lease so that etcd automatically clears key1 and key2 when the lease
> expires.
>
> If you want to keep the lease, you need to periodically call the
> KeeyAlive method to refresh it. For example, to check whether a
> process in a distributed system is alive, you can create a lease in
> the process and periodically call the KeepAlive method in the process.
> If the process is normal, the lease on this node is kept. If the
> process crashes, the lease automatically expires.
>
> However, if a large number of keys need to support a similar lease
> mechanism, and the lease must be refreshed for each key independently,
> this puts a great deal of pressure on etcd. Therefore, etcd allows the
> binding of multiple keys (for example, keys with similar expiration
> times) to the same lease, which can greatly reduce the overhead of
> lease refresh and improve etcd performance.